# 2D array to 3D area function - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d

I am trying to write a function that creates a 3D surface of a 2D input numpy array, having the number of rows and columns as X and X, and the values in the array as the Z values. I searched on SO for examples of 3D plots, and adapted this example ([Plotting a 2d Array with mplot3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409690/plotting-a-2d-array-with-mplot3d)) into the function below:

```
def area_plot(a):
    rows = range(a.shape[0])
    columns = range(a.shape[1])
    hf = plt.figure()
    ha = hf.add_subplot(111, projection= "3d")
    X, Y = np.mgrid(rows, columns)
    ha.plot_surface(X,Y, arr)
    plt.show()
```

The example array is this:

```
arr = np.array([(1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,3,10,3,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,1)])

area_plot(arr)
```

But I get this error, and I don't know how to fix it. Thanks!

> TypeError: 'nd_grid' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you weren't using `np.mgrid` correctly. See below:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def area_plot(a):
    rows = range(a.shape[0])
    columns = range(a.shape[1])
    hf = plt.figure()
    ha = hf.add_subplot(111, projection= "3d")
    X, Y = np.mgrid[0: len(rows), 0:len(columns)]
    ha.plot_surface(X,Y, a)
    plt.show()

arr = np.array([(1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,3,10,3,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1),
                (1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,1)])

area_plot(arr)
```

Comment: This code yields a *ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged*

Comment: I get this error message: 'ValueError: shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 0.'

Comment: @LPR That fixes the *ValueError* and is most likely what the OP is looking for.